# Question: Planet 9 a Black Hole

Tags: black-hole, 9th-planet

I had a shower thought.

"Is it possible that the mysterious 9th or 10th planet is in fact a small Black Hole"?

Comment: P9, if it exists has a mass around 7 Earth masses. A planetary body and a black hole of 7 Earth masses has the exact same gravitational field outside a few Schwarzschild radii.

Comment: Also see this questin about planet nine: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50923/what-is-the-likelyhood-that-planet-x-is-a-glass-not-a-typo-for-gas-planet-wha/50951#50951

Comment: ...and the other linked questions at the proposed duplicate. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Don't worry if your first question is closed as a duplicate, that happens to all of us. Next time you can try the search bar or as you are typing look for suggested similar questions to see if it's been asked before.